# generating paths with django and python, what is the request object

Tags: python, django, path, request

This is my first experience with Django so there's probably an obvious solution I'm not aware of.

I have an assignment of creating an encyclopedia-like website, one objective is creating pages for each article that I have.
I've created a function in my "views" file:

```
def title_page(request, title):
    if title not in util.list_entries():
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
    return render(request, f"encyclopedia/title.html", {
        "page_name": title,
        "content": util.get_entry(title)
    })
```

where `util.list_entries()` is a function that supplies the list of article names and `util.get_entry` is a function that supplies the content of said article name.

in my "urls" file i have a list of url patterns that holds all of my paths:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index")
]
```

I tried to create a loop to append a path for each article that I have:

```
for entry in util.list_entries():
    urlpatterns.append(path(f"<str:{entry}>", views.title_page(entry), name=entry))
```

however i get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: title_page() missing 1 required positional argument: 'title'
```

I suppose that `title_page` function requires the request object but I'm not sure how to access it and how to pass it through the paths function, and moreover in functions like the `index` function that requires no other positional arguments :

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
```

the urls path

```
path("", views.index, name="index")
```

seems to work without the request object as an argument so I don't understand why in the first situation it doesn't.

Any idea will be of major help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry too much about the request object at this point. You're right - the views need it, but as long as you include it in the function definition then django will look after that.

Your error is because your view expects to receive a title, but your URL isn't passing it through.

Take this example from the django [URL docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments);

```py
# URLconf
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', views.page),
    path('blog/page<int:num>/', views.page),
]

# View (in blog/views.py)
def page(request, num=1):
    # Output the appropriate page of blog entries, according to num.
    ...
```

As you can see here, `num` is expected in the view and given a default value, it's also defined in the URL above, with requests to both `/blog/` and `/blog/3` hitting the same view.

Where requests come through to `/blog/` the default value of `1` is used for the `num` variable.

So your view `title_page` might have a URL like;

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('page/<str:title>/', views.title_page, name='page'),
]
```

Then title would be available to your view where it's not at the moment.

You can then link to your view with the following HTML tag from django;

```html
<a href="{% url 'page' 'News' %}">News</a>
```